# Python 2.7.3 IDLE wont open

Tags: python, windows-7, python-2.7, python-idle

I'm using windows 7 64-bit and python 2.7.3 32-bit and the IDLE wont open.
I had python 2.7.3 64-bit (and the IDLE was fine) - but i needed the 32 to run some code.
any ideas?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

open up cmd or powershell and type in this:

```
C:\path\to\python.exe -m idlelib.idle
```

where of course \path\to\python.exe is your local path to python executable. do you see any error there?

Comment: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Python27\lib\runpy.py", line 162, in _run_module_as_main
    "__main__", fname, loader, pkg_name)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\runpy.py", line 72, in _run_code
    exec code in run_globals
  File "C:\Python27\lib\idlelib\idle.py", line 10, in <module>
    import idlelib.PyShell
  File "C:\Python27\lib\idlelib\idlelib.py", line 10, in <module>
    import idlelib.PyShell
ImportError: No module named PyShell

Comment: this probably means that your idle is finding only 64bit modules (that's why it fails to import). how did you switch between 64 and 32 bit? did you do a clean install of python or just overwrote the previous?

Comment: completely remove all your python then, and try again from a fresh start :) you have same version, different architecture. probably it didn't overwrite the old libs (not sure, but it's worth a try)

Comment: hoped there will be an easier way... Thanks @Samuele !

Comment: it's not hard at all, it's just boring. but still better than keeping some bugged/faulted libraries around :) btw, try and let me know if this solves your problem or not...

Comment: i know. but i used easy_install to install all sort of stuff and i don't want it all to go away

Answer (score 2):

Uninstall the 64 bits Python 2.7 and install 32 bits Python 2.7. Then your IDLE will work fine.